# Python 3.6, using tkinter, gives me the spinning beachball forever. (mac)

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, tkinter

I am using python 3.6 for the mac. i have recently just begun working with GUI and have started with a simple messagebox.showinfo pop up. However, when i run the program , the messagebox shows, but when i click 'ok', it doesnt go away and i'm just stuck with the spinning beachball until i manually close the program.

I know this isn't a problem with my code as it works fine on the windows operating system, as i have run the code on a windows computer as well.

**this is the function that the messagebox pops up from:**

```
def greeting():
    greetingFile = open("greetingFile.txt", "w")
    greetingFile.write(messagebox.showinfo("Welcome to the board game!","In this game, you will navigate"\
                        " across a 7x7 grid and the first player to reach square 49 wins."\
                        " Both players start on space 1."))
greetingFile.close()
return
```

**this is the main bit of my code where i call the function:**

```
greeting()
greetingFile = open("greetingFile.txt", "r")
greetingFile.close()
```

**this is a new code i made, that is supposed to do the same thing: show a messagebox, and close.**

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tkinter.Tk() 
root.withdraw()

def greeting():
    greetingFile = open("greetingFile.txt", "w")
    greetingFile.write(messagebox.showinfo("Welcome to the board game!", "In this game, you will navigate"\
                        " across a 7x7 grid and the first player to reach square 49 wins."\
                        " Both players start on space 1."))
    greetingFile.close()
    return

greeting()
greetingFile = open("greetingFile.txt", "r")
greetingFile.close()
```

when i run it, it works, but when i click 'ok' to close the messagebox it freezes and the spinning beachball appears. this does not happen when i run it on a windows pc

Comment: Please post code as formatted text.

Comment: There's the code, however i don't think it's anything wrong with the code, but with the operating system

Comment: Look, macOS is being built by at least _tens_ of professional programmers for _16 years_. So, it's much more likely that there's a problem in _your_ code. Also, that's not the full code, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have provided a new code which is what i am trying to do, but it still will not let me close the messagebox.

Comment: why are you trying to write a message box to a file?

Comment: I'm doing a project, and this is one of the requirements. I've tried running the code without doing this and i still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some other problems similar to yours.

It may be caused by not calling `mainloop()` at the end of your program.

the example code you have does not show us you are using `root.mainloop()` so try adding that to the end of your program and see if that helps.

If that does not help you could add `root.update()` just before the messagebox dialog.

Here is a modified version of your code with both `update()` and `mainloop()` added. Let me know if this helps.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tkinter.Tk() 
root.withdraw()

def greeting():
    greetingFile = open("greetingFile.txt", "w")

    root.update() # added the update method to force an update of the events
    greetingFile.write(messagebox.showinfo("Welcome to the board game!", "In this game, you will navigate"\
                        " across a 7x7 grid and the first player to reach square 49 wins."\
                        " Both players start on space 1."))
    greetingFile.close()
    return

greeting()
greetingFile = open("greetingFile.txt", "r")
greetingFile.close()

root.mainloop() # needed for all tkinter programs to work properly.
```

Alternatively we can call messagebox separately from the write method. This might be part of the hangup with the program.

So instead set showinfo to a variable and then use that variable in the write method.

Code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tkinter.Tk() 
root.withdraw()

def greeting():
    greetingFile = open("greetingFile.txt", "w")
    my_var = messagebox.showinfo("Welcome to the board game!", "In this game, you will navigate"\
                        " across a 7x7 grid and the first player to reach square 49 wins."\
                        " Both players start on space 1.")
    greetingFile.write(my_var)
    greetingFile.close()
    # I changed as little code as possible but just to let you know the use
    # of return here does nothing for your program.
    return

greeting()
greetingFile = open("greetingFile.txt", "r")
greetingFile.close()
```

One last option if you cannot work out the issues with messagebox and mac that you are having is to create your own messagebox.

We can accomplish this with `Toplevel()` and you can format everything the way you want it unlike messagebox with its limited features.

I have a example below. Let me know if that helps.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk() 
root.withdraw()

def save_greeting_verification(top):
    greetingFile = open("greetingFile.txt", "w")
    greetingFile.write("Ok")
    greetingFile.close()
    top.destroy()

def greeting():
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    top.geometry("350x80")
    top.resizable(False, False)
    top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: save_greeting_verification(top))
    top.title("Welcome to the board game!")
    tk.Label(top, text = "In this game, you will navigate\nacross a 7x7 grid and the first player to reach square 49 wins.\nBoth players start on space 1.").pack()
    tk.Button(top, text = "ok", command = lambda: save_greeting_verification(top)).pack()

greeting()
greetingFile = open("greetingFile.txt", "r")
print(greetingFile.read())
greetingFile.close()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this and the messagebox still won't close and gives me the beach ball. This is why i think that it's a problem with the operating system or maybe my computer.

Comment: @A.Dedich It may be a version bug with either python or tkinter.

Comment: @A.Dedich I updated my example as I think update needs to be called before the messagebox dialog.

Comment: i have tried running the updated version of your code(thanks for your tips), but the same problem still persists. i have tried switching to different versions of python, but nothing changes.

Comment: @A. Dedich that seams very odd 2 me. Many people have had issues with different messageboxs in mac and the issue is normally `mainloop()` or `update()`. I will keep searching if I find something I will update my answer.

Comment: @A.Dedich have you tried just running messagebox by itself. something like `root = tkinter.Tk() / root.withdraw() / messagebox.showinfo("Test", "test") / root.mainloop()`. Just to see if you can run a messagebox without issues.

Comment: @A.Dedich also try running it without doing `withdraw()` just to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @A.Dedich One last edit to my answer. I have added an alternative by creating your own top level window. This may help you with the issue you are having but I am not sure if it will be acceptable for your project.

Comment: Thank you for all your help and sorry for the late reply. Your edited verison of the code seems to work, but I still don't know why the original version with messagebox didn't work. Do you have any ideas? Could it be a problem with the Mac operating system?

Comment: My project will be checked on windows computers, and it worked perfectly fine when i ran it on a windows pc, so there is no problem with the code. But i do all coding on the mac OS, which is why i wanted to know how to fix this issue.

Comment: @A.Dedich I doubt it is an issue with Mac vs an issue with the python/tkinter distro for Mac. But without being about to find a solid report as to why something like this is happening it is hard to say.